# Unfamiliar inequality with positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite

I came across this inequality in a proof and I'm not sure where it came from. Here, $g$ is the gradient of a multivariable function $f$ and $B$ is an approximation of the Hessian of said function $f$. $B$ was said to be positive definite:

$$-\frac 12\frac{\Vert{g}\Vert^4}{g^{T}Bg}\le-\frac 12\frac{\Vert{g}\Vert^4}{\Vert{B}\Vert\Vert{g}\Vert^2}$$

What exactly is the relation between $g^{T}Bg$ and the norm of $B$ that allows us to say this?

Comment: What is the norm on the matrix here? Is it the operator norm or the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Why do you say determinant of $B$? Rewrite this and you want to see that $g^\top Bg \le \|B\|\|g\|^2$. Think of $g^\top Bg$ as an inner product and use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: My bad for misinterpreting the notation! I did not realise that it meant the norm and not the determinant. But the proof does not mention which norm it is using so I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Answer (score 1):

After canceling the other terms, your inequality reduces to
$$g^\top B g \overset{?}{\le} \|B\|\|g\|^2.$$

First, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies $g^\top B g \le \|g\| \|Bg\|$.

Next, the inequality $\|Bg\| \le \|B\| \|g\|$ follows from the definition of the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions) of the matrix $B$.